# Using redeclaration within a block scope

Tags: c++, using-declaration

Here is the code which causes a compile-time error:

```
#include <iostream>

int a;

void f()
{
    using ::a;
    using ::a; //'a' is already declared in this scope. 
}

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/323bc5fd7274f88b)**

What the standard says is (`N4296::7.3.3/10 [namespace.udecl]`):

> A using-declaration is a declaration and can therefore be used
>   repeatedly where (and only where) multiple declarations are allowed.

So, I supposed that any redeclaration is ill-formed in the block scope. But the program

```
#include <iostream>

void f()
{
    extern int a;
    extern int a;
}

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb5351182c8066b9)**

works fine. So why is the using redeclaration actually prevented from appearing twice in the block scope?

Comment: The "... can therefore be used repeatedly" doesn't necessarily imply that you can use the same name repeatedly.  It just means you can write several `using ...;` statements at the beginning of the block.

Comment: @Rufflewind Yes, but it doesn't answer my question because it's still unclear why we can't redeclare a name by a using declaration in the same scope.

Comment: The official standard actually gives an *explicit example* that [forbids what you are doing right now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4252451), but not all compilers detect it and it is a bit inconsistent with the rest of the language, as stated in [this defect report on C++ standard](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#36).

Comment: Extern can be declared as many times as you want

Comment: Is there a reason not to close this as a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4252451 as suggested by @Rufflewind?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, now it's perectly clear.