# A using-declaration can not be repeated in function scope. Why is that?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, using-declaration

In [namespace.udecl]/10 you have the following example:

```
namespace A {
    int i;
}
namespace A1 {
    using A::i;
    using A::i; // OK: double declaration
}
void f() {
    using A::i;
    using A::i; // error: double declaration
}
```

This snippet compiles in clang.

Comment: What practical problem does this cause you?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: This question is a language-laywer question. There need not be any practical problems for such questions for them to be interesting. There are about the definition of the programming language.

Comment: @Supremum: [_"if your question generally covers… a practical, answerable problem… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) It might be interesting but it is not on-topic.

Comment: The answer to this related question solves this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224886/program-with-chaining-of-using-declarations-compiles-on-msvs-and-clang-but-not-o Observe that the example [namespace.udecl]/10 is incorrect and has just been changed in response to my related question.

Comment: This question seems very related also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252451/namespace-using-declaration-bug-in-gcc-vs2010

Answer (score 7):

The first is a declaration inside a namespace, and the multiple using statements could happen frequently using #includes. The second is inside a definition of a function, and you would never do that unless you made a mistake. You can't define the same symbol twice either, for example, but you can declare several times.

The using statement is also more than just a declaration. It is a bit stronger, as it imports a function from one namespace to another. For example, it can pull a protected base class member function into a derived class, making it public. It's almost a definition by linkage.

Comment: Could you provide a quote from the standard?

Comment: The answer to this related question solves this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224886/program-with-chaining-of-using-declarations-compiles-on-msvs-and-clang-but-not-o Observe that the example [namespace.udecl]/10 is incorrect and has just been changed in response to my related question.